# CSS: ::selection { background: #000000; color: #ffffff } not appearing as full black

Tags: css, colors, selection

```
::selection { background: #000000; color: #ffffff }
```

Is resulting in a dark grey selection color, not full black (`#000000`). Changing opacity makes no difference.

How do I make the selection color appear as `#ffffff`?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/TfDTR/). Are you sure you're not just looking at your screen from an angle? `:)` (If not... which browser?)

Comment: It might be inheriting opacity from a parent element

Comment: The problem is in safari

Comment: @minitech It's dark grey on Chrome 15 on Lion. If you change the foreground color to black you'll see the distinction more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/divad12/TfDTR/1/ It's completely black on FF 8 though.

Comment: @DavidHu: I tried it on Chrome 16, Windows 7 x64, and it looked dark grey, but then I changed the background and text [and it was apparently just an illusion](http://jsfiddle.net/TfDTR/3/). (Yes, it is *very* slightly brighter [only visible from a very high angle] but that's probably due to LCD light leakage.)

Comment: Not an illusion in Safari. Definitely being displayed as rgb(50,50,50) or rgb(51,51,51).

Comment: I know this was long time ago but I'm gonna add this information here. The best way, which will get you the color with the values (1, 1, 1) that is black to a human eye is to use `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, calc(1 - 1 / 256));`. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42781736/7393973).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
::selection {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
   color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. In Safari for Lion this resulted in a value of (2,2,2) which is better than the (50,50,50) I was seeing otherwise. If you set the background-colour of the parent container to black then the highlight automatically is fully black (0,0,0) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had to change the code to background-color instead since the above solution did not work for me.

```
::selection {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```