# Full opaque black text selection

Tags: html, css

**Edit explaining why this isn't duplicated:**
As I said in the comment, it's not exactly duplicated because the answer there isn't the solution here. Here I started explaining how I got it as `(1, 1, 1)` and wanted it to be `(0, 0, 0)`, while there they didn't went has far precise and got it only to `(2, 2, 2)`. You could say the question is the same one but I think mine is better explained and I needed a good answer for the information that I provided.

By default, the background color of the text selection is blue with some opacity.

I tried to make it full black by using `::selection` and testing the alpha value of `rgba()` but the closest I only got was `rgb(1, 1, 1)`. Is it possible to get `rgb(0, 0, 0)`? Here's the code:

```css
::selection {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.996093750000000055511151231257827021181583404);
  color: #fff;
}

textarea {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea autofocus onfocus="this.select()" spellcheck="false">Text.</textarea>
```

If I change it to `0.996093750000000055511151231257827021181583405` I get `rgb(51, 51, 51)` for some strange reason. Where do these randoms numbers come from anyway? I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: As far I could understand you question, is you want to remove `opacity` of selection, that's why pure black `#000` is becoming `rgb(51,51,51)` (#333). I guess there is no way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's my question @AbhishekPandey. What I wanted was to see was if anyone knew anyway to achieve it because I also don't know which is why I think it's impossible, but better be sure than sorry.

Comment: You can discuss your question **[here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: ::selection { background: #000000; color: #ffffff } not appearing as full black](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372334/css-selection-background-000000-color-ffffff-not-appearing-as-full-b)

Comment: It's not exactly duplicated because the answer there isn't the solution here, @AbhishekPandey. Here I started explaining how I got it as (1, 1, 1) and wanted it to be (0, 0, 0), while there they didn't went has far precise and only got it to (2, 2, 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [..] I get rgb(51, 51, 51) for some strange reason.[..]

**A little trivia**:

This pseudo-element `::selection` was in the drafts of CSS Selectors Level 3, but was removed during the Candidate Recommendation phase.

See here: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selection

However, it was added again in Pseudo-Elements Level 4.

See here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-selectors

I tried to dig up the old refs, like this one: https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#UIfragments; but I couldn't find the problem you are facing.

**Reason**:

I draw upon the [Level-4 specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-selectors), which says this:

> For non-replaced content, the UA must honor the color and
>   background-color (including their alpha channels) as specified.
>   However, for replaced content, the UA should create a semi-transparent
>   wash to coat the content so that it can show through the selection.
>   This wash should be of the specified background-color if that is not
>   transparent, else of the specified color; however the UA may adjust
>   the alpha channel if it is opaque

So, what you are seeing is actually the *wash* that is being implemented by the UA.

That explains the behaviour on replaced content like that of textareas and inputs. However, although the specs say that for non-replaced content, the UA **must** honor the colors (with alpha channels); it seems the browsers have not yet completely implemented the spec (*i.e. level-4 so to speak*). They anyway aren't bound to. Heck they haven't agreed on complete level-3 compliance.

And, `::selection` is anyway deprecated in level-3! So, this is the closest to the reason you can get. Live with it.

Comment: I will live with it since there's no other option, but it will be a sad life.

Comment: I guess this is just not important enough just like a bunch of other customizable limits in web pages because everyone loves the default way of everything and are, most of time, against changing it because, poor users of the page and that stuff (even thought I'm not creating any site, I just like to code and see the result myself. But I have been finding some bad limits of how far a developer can customize his work which sads me).

Comment: @user7393973: I can understand your pain. As developers our first point of reference is the specs. If it is defined behaviour, we need to work around that. If it isn't or the specs aren't decipherable, we seek help.

Comment: Just to make sure nobody gets me wrong: I'm not making a big deal for the 1 value (which the difference isn't notable with the human eye), I'm just mad that so many simple things don't work or are more complex than what they should be. I'm no professional but I'm sure those things I'm talking about could easly be fixed by the developers of this stuff. Anyway, goodbye to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I found the formula/reason to why it's impossible the way I'm trying.

That "random number" is `1 - (1 / 256)` which in another words means, it doesn't let me have opaque, it has to have the minimum of opacity that does change the original color without it, which makes the `rgb(1, 1, 1)` never get to `rgb(0, 0, 0)` no matter how many decimal numbers I find.

So unless there's another technique of changing the color of the text selection that I'm not aware of, it's impossible to obtain full actuall opaque black, only black with the minimum opacity/transparency which nobody can see the diference at human eye but still, it will always be `rgba(1, 1, 1)`. :c

The other advanced, complex and unecessary way is to use hacks/tricks/workarounds with a lot of fake visual effects and probably JavaScript which is totally not worth the ammount of work.

Resuming: Alpha with the value `1` is opaque, all the values between `1` and `1 - (1/256)` still are too but I can't use those values as it apparently doesn't allow me to use opaque so I can only use between `0` and `1 - (1/256)`. I'm not sure which if the exact result of `1 - (1/256)` is opaque or not.

So the best way is to use `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, calc(1 - 1 / 256));`.

Comment: `background-color: black;` :P

Comment: No @RaisingAgent, read the questions, the answers and the comments.

Comment: You could open a Chrome ticket, they are always pretty fast. Might give more insight on this issue. Also, it might be somethign they haven't thought about before.

Comment: [`:P`](http://emojipedia.org/face-with-stuck-out-tongue/), "Used as a way of stating “I’m kidding” or generally being jovial and not serious."

Comment: @RaisingAgent, I know, I use it too. ^-^

Comment: @RaisingAgent, I think they "droped" this in terms that they don't care much about it. There was never actually much development in to that CSS selector in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the color codes in Hex format.

So, your `::selection` becomes:

```
::selection {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: That will make it `rgb(51, 51, 51)`.

Comment: `#000` is equivalent to `rgb(0, 0, 0)` or `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)`. Anyway when I put in hex code (`#000`), I see it as `#000` and not in `RGB`.

Comment: Have you actually tried that code or you're talking what you think it does?

Comment: I have tried it in the code you put above. Check and go inspect: https://jsfiddle.net/75ahjutc/

Comment: I can't check it right now because I'm using a protected internet but [here's how it works to me](http://i.imgur.com/7GNPSqk.png).